# Arduino Uno not turning on

Tags: arduino-uno

I have bought an arduino uno but when i plugged in the arduino to my laptop its not turned on (the built-in LED was off) and at the arduino IDE I wasnt able to change the port (the port button was unavalible)
what should I do for the arduino uno board to work?

Comment: Check your USB cable first. If that is fine, check your USB port. If that is fine then, if it's a genuine Arduino return it for a replacement or refund. If it's a cheap Chinese clone then throw it in the bin and buy a *real* Arduino.

Comment: If you have an Arduino clone with a CH340G chip, you need to install a CH340G driver.

Comment: Not having the driver won't keep it from powering on tho, that will just prevent comm's.

Comment: @CrossRoads, true indeed.

Comment: I second @Majenko; cheap clones are very prone to fail out-of-the-box. That said, what laptop do you have? What Operating System? How is your laptop powered (ie. perhaps USB isn't able to handle the electricity needed)? What happens if you power it from a power supply connected to your household mains voltage?

Comment: You could check (measure with a DMM) whether you see 5V at the 5V pin.